# WCF: Adding BehaviorExtensions generates a security exception

Tags: wcf

When adding a `<behaviorExtensions>` section to the web.config file of my project I get a security exception (see below). What can be the problem? I follow this solution to another issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354727/in-wcf-web-programming-model-how-can-one-write-a-operation-contract-with-an-arra)

Adding this:

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="customWebHttp" type="CloudService4_WebRole.CustomHttpBehaviorExtensionElement, CloudService4_WebRole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

results in:

```
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed.
```

Comment: seems like you're dealing with a security issue on a computer here - don't think this has anything to do with WCF per se.

Comment: Is the assembly with the behavior extension stored on e.g. a network path (UNC-style addressed)?