# WCF method not accepting nulls for nullable int parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, int, nullable

I have a WCF method which compiles fine with a nullable int as a parameter.  However, when I reference the service from another project, it expects an ordinary int as a parameter.  From reading other stackoverflow threads it seems that it is possible to have a nullable int parameter, however, I cannot work out how to implement it.

My code is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string CompletePayment(int paymentType, int? userId)
}


public class Service : IService
{

    public string CompletePayment(int paymentType, int? userId)
    {
        return "it worked";
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`int?` is just syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>` and I think there are some restrictions when using generics in service contracts. See this answer: [Can a WCF service contract have a nullable input parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393359/can-a-wcf-service-contract-have-a-nullable-input-parameter)