# How to apply two Endpoint Behaviors to one behavior configuration?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, behavior, endpoint

This question is a follow up to @joshperry's answer on [CustomQueryStringConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354727/in-wcf-web-programming-model-how-can-one-write-a-operation-contract-with-an-arra).  I implemented this solution with a small modification.  My version converts `System.Int32[]` instead of `string[]`.

However, I have a problem with my WCF configuration.  My service dishes out SOAP, XML and JSON.  SOAP wasn't a problem, this solution works for XML, but JSON is still messed up.  I tried  found out that the class that does JSON conversion automatically ([enableWebScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webscriptenablingbehavior.aspx) behavior) is a sealed class, so I can't override it like you did for `WebHttpBehavior`.  I also tried adding two behaviors, but that didn't work either:

```
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="xmlBehavior">          
          <ArrayQuerystring />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">                    
          <ArrayQuerystring />
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>
```

I think it might be an ordering issue?  If I put the `ArrayQuerystring` behavior first, I get no results.  If I put it second, then I get the same results as the XML endpoint.  How do I apply your CustomQuerystringConverter to a JSON endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON parser already supports arrays. You can pass them on the URL line like this:

```
...?ID=2&includedCollections=["Addresses","Phones"]
```